# How to decode &#39 in flask with Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

When I'm trying to write errors from wtforms in Jinja2 template, it returns undecoded quote. How can i fix it?

```
{% if registrationForm.errors %}
    <script>swal("Error!", "{{ registrationForm.errors['password'] }}", "error")</script>
{% endif %}
```

Errors are equal to

```
{'email': ['This field is required.'], 'username': ['This field is required.'], 'acceptTOS': ['This field is required.'], 'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing'], 'password': ['This field is required.']}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe) template filter - it tells jinja2 to not apply any further filters.

> Marks a string as being safe for inclusion in HTML/XML output without
>   needing to be escaped.

usage Example:

```
{{ errors|safe }}
```

Or to,

```
{{ errors | tojson | safe }}
```

---

Or can also mark it safe using [`Markup`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Markup) in Flask.

Comment: Works well, but "tojson | safe" throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: I just suggested {{ errors | safe }} is enough - in earlier versions of flask {{ errors | tojson | safe }} was used to come in use.

Comment: In the end, i solved many more problems with this `<script>swal("Error!", "{% for error in registrationForm.errors.keys() %}[{{ error }}] {{ registrationForm.errors[error][0] }}\n{% endfor %}", "error")</script>`

Comment: {{ errors | tojson | safe }} or {{ errors | tojson }}  works for me

but not {{ errors|safe }}

Comment: I tried using {{ errors | tojson | safe }} but in the chrome dev tools it is not reflecting i can only see {{ errors | tojson }} can you please tell me why ?