# &#39; HTML number showing instad of '

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a web service in which I want to have Google Charts.

I have a script that creates a data in format that is acceptable by google.visualization.arrayToDataTable and passes it in a string format into a variable google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{ data }})

When I have my html template and I inster the string with data myself, everything renders perfectly and when I access the source code I see:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], [0.0, 10.0, 12.48], [1.0, 1.0, 5.64], [2.0, 5.0, 3.68], [3.0, 3.0, 3.2], [4.0, 3.0, 3.52], [5.0, 2.0, 2.16], [6.0, 1.0, 1.76], [7.0, 0.0, 1.32], [8.0, 0.0, 1.68], [9.0, 0.0, 0.8], [10.0, 2.0, 0.76], [11.0, 0.0, 0.92], [12.0, 2.0, 0.96], [13.0, 2.0, 1.32], [14.0, 0.0, 1.0799999999999996], [15.0, 0.0, 0.96], [16.0, 0.0, 0.68], [17.0, 1.0, 0.52], [18.0, 0.0, 0.44], [19.0, 1.0, 0.28], [20.0, 0.0, 0.4], [21.0, 0.0, 0.68], [22.0, 1.0, 0.44], [23.0, 0.0, 0.16], [24.0, 0.0, 0.08], [25.0, 1.0, 0.08], [26.0, 0.0, 0.16], [27.0, 1.0, 0.32], [28.0, 0.0, 0.48], [29.0, 0.0, 0.4], [30.0, 0.0, 3.2]]);

        var options = {
          title: 'perc_diff',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However when I call this website using my Flask app using render_template method, I get:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[&#39;var1&#39;, &#39;var2&#39;, &#39;var3&#39;], [0.0, 10.0, 12.48], [1.0, 1.0, 5.64], [2.0, 5.0, 3.68], [3.0, 3.0, 3.2], [4.0, 3.0, 3.52], [5.0, 2.0, 2.16], [6.0, 1.0, 1.76], [7.0, 0.0, 1.32], [8.0, 0.0, 1.68], [9.0, 0.0, 0.8], [10.0, 2.0, 0.76], [11.0, 0.0, 0.92], [12.0, 2.0, 0.96], [13.0, 2.0, 1.32], [14.0, 0.0, 1.0799999999999996], [15.0, 0.0, 0.96], [16.0, 0.0, 0.68], [17.0, 1.0, 0.52], [18.0, 0.0, 0.44], [19.0, 1.0, 0.28], [20.0, 0.0, 0.4], [21.0, 0.0, 0.68], [22.0, 1.0, 0.44], [23.0, 0.0, 0.16], [24.0, 0.0, 0.08], [25.0, 1.0, 0.08], [26.0, 0.0, 0.16], [27.0, 1.0, 0.32], [28.0, 0.0, 0.48], [29.0, 0.0, 0.4], [30.0, 0.0, 3.2]]);

        var options = {
          title: 'perc_diff',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the page doesn't want deisplay the google chart. The template is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{ data }});

        var options = {
          title: 'perc_diff',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where data is passed as in a string format from the python Flask application.

I believe that the reason behind the error is " ' " being replaced by " ' " when rendering.

Can anyone be as nice as to help me resolve that issue?

Comment: Haven't used flask before, but this may be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077534/how-to-decode-39-in-flask-with-jinja2-template

Comment: Thanks a tonne! It worked!!

Comment: It worked after changine {{ data }} to {{ data|safe }}

Answer (score 0):

It worked after changine {{ data }} to {{ data|safe }}